# Limit Dropdown Options For Datasource Relationship

Tags: google-app-maker

**Short Version:**

Need to limit the options (run a query) of a dropdown that is in a table with a relationship datasource. The field of the query exists in the OWNER datasource, while the field of the dropdown exists in the non-OWNER (child?)

---

**Long Version:**

I have a system setup to organize PO requests.

Model **PORequest** = holds PO numbers, etc.

Queried Datasource **PORequest_HideArchived** = holds all POs, but has the query:

```
Archived != :ArchivedStatus
```

Where the Archived status is set for 'Yes'. Therefore all POs with 'Yes' in the ArchivedStatus field are hidden.

Datasource **PORequest_Items** = holds the items for each PO request

I have setup a ONE to MANY relationship with PORequest as the owner.

---

So now I can generate a PORequest (left) and add items to that PO via a table (middle + right) with the datasource: **PORequest_HideArchived:PORequest_Items (relation)**.

[image]

So far so good.

That table on the far right is where I am running into a problem. I want to be able to move a PO Item from one PO to another. The easiest way to do that is change the PORequestNumber field of the item (**datasource = PORequest_HideArchived**) that is linked via the relationship.

[image]

All this works great too.

Only problem is that when I click the dropdown for the PORequestNumber I can see ALL the PORequestNumber entries, instead of JUST the POs that aren't archived.

[image]

So instead of seeing 1-6, I should only be seeing the active POs (1, 5, 6)

The panel that the table is in has the datasource: **PORequest_HideArchived:PORequest_Items (relation)**

But the Row that the PORequestNumber field is in has the datasource: **PORequest_Items**.

Therefore my query on the PORequest_HideArchived datasource has no effect.

Any way I can run this query so the dropdown options are limited to ArchivedStatus = 'No'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set filtered datasource for the dropdown options/names:

```js
@datasources.PORequest_HideArchived.items
```

and for the dropdown select row's item relation:

```js
@datatsource.item.PORequest
```

Comment: This totally worked! Thank you! I figured it was something simple.